# Prove that the king made at least one diagonal move.

Tags: logic

I am having trouble understanding the solution to the question, how does when it starts on a black square must end on another black square, and if the king's moves change the colors of the squares how does that constitute making the number of traversed squares odd?

**Question:**
A king Visited all squares of the usual 8 by 8 chessboard exactly once starting from the lower left square (a1) and finishing at the upper right square (h8). Prove that the king made at least one diagonal move.

**Answer:**
Assume on the contrary that the king made no diagonal moves. then on each move it changed the color of it's square. Consider a list of all squares in the order the king visited them. It starts with a white square and ends with a white square, and the colors of the squares alternate. Therefore it has an odd number of squares. but the king visited all 64 squares exactly once. a contradiction. therefore the king made at least 1 diagonal move.

Comment: There are $64$ squares in total, which means that the King must make $63$ moves.  If each move changes the color, then the King will end in a square of a different color, as $63$ is odd.  To visualize it, I suggest working with a smaller board.  For $2\times 2$, there isn't much to it.  Look at $4\times 4$.

Comment: @lulu That's an answer to the question. Why are you putting it in the comment section and not as an answer?

Comment: @Arthur, because I expect the question to be closed soon.  But maybe I'm wrong about that, so I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

There are $64$ squares in total, which means that the King must make $63$ moves.  If each move changes the color, then the King will end in a square of a different color, as $63$ is odd.  To visualize it, I suggest working with a smaller board.  For $2\times 2$, there isn't much to it, so look at $4\times 4$.